# Point Correspondence in 2D in two image

Tags: geometry

I have taken two image from two different camera and lens from 3 fixed point which makes a 90 degree angle on a plane. the position of camera when taking photo is also changed but the 3 fixed points are in both images.

How can I find a relation to map points in these two images? I just want to map the points on the plane which 3 fixed points are.

Comment: The question is hard to understand as formulated. Is this a correct summary? You took two images from two different camera positions. There are three fixed points that appear in both images, and they form a right triangle. You can identify these three points in both images, and thus can obtain their 2D coordinates in each of the images, and now you're looking for a map between the 2D coordinates in the two images such that image points mapped to each other are images of the same 3D point?

Comment: @joriki: approximately yes, 3 points are making a 90 degree angle in real world, and I just want to find the correspondence in a plane which these 3 points are, for example just roof of a building which is photographed and 3 fixed point are on the roof.

Answer (score 1):

See [Epipolar geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epipolar_geometry) and the [Correspondence problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_problem).